# C++ from Microsoft to Mac

Tags: macos

I need to write a c++ program in Windows8 that will be later moved to MAC. As I understand Eclipse IDE runs on Mac with C++.
Would it be possible to have an Eclipse installed in Windows 8 as IDE, build the classes and the Main program and then make it run on a MAC that also has installed Eclipse? 
Thank you for any indications/suggestions.
Alfred

Comment: you don't need eclipse to run a program.  you need eclipse (or other IDE) to WRITE the program.  If you are saying that you need to RUN the program on a mac, then you can either A: compile it as such on the windows machine, or B: copy the sourcecode to a mac and compile it there.  The resulting binary is what you actually run.

Comment: @RussellUhl You don't really need Eclipse or any other IDE to write the program, either. There is plenty of code written with no IDE involved at all...

Comment: @twalberg yea i know, but I was keeping it simple.  I actually write coldfusion in notepad++ for a living, currently.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you misunderstand what Eclipse is used for.

The way you posed the question is like asking, "if I have a pen and I write a book in English, they also have pens in France, so will the book I write be able to be read and understood in France, by a person who can only understand French"

Like the pen, Eclipse is just a tool, which is used to write code. The code written is what matters, not the tool used to write it.

What you can do, is use a cross platform framework, such as [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) to develop the code. This can then be compiled on both Windows and OSX, allowing the code to be written just once and executed on both platforms.